# custom listview with only one checkbox is selected one at a time

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a custom listview with each row contaning a checkbox and text. now what i want that if any one checkbox of listview row is checked so others checkbox in other row if checked .it will be delected automatically.(i.e only one checkbox should be selected one at a time).how should i do that.

So far what i have done is as follows:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    List<String> items;

     boolean array[];


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    array =new boolean[items.size()];
}


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v=convertView;
        final int pos=position;
        if(v==null)
        {
            v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list,null);
        }

        TextView txt1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final CheckBox chkbox=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        txt1.setText(items.get(position));
        int selectedindexitem=0;
        chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(chkbox.isChecked())
                {
                    array[pos]=true;


                }else{
                    array[pos]=false;
                }
            }
        }); 
        chkbox.setChecked(array[pos]);





        return v; 
    }




}

In this code i can select multiple checkbox at a time but i need only one checkbox should be checked one at a time.
```

Comment: Since you're using a checkbox in your view instead of the one in the listview you should uncheck them manually. And for that you need to keep a reference of which you have selected and which not.

Comment: A very simple way to do it is that just replace your CheckBox with RadioButtons and make sure that all the RadioButtons are in same RadioGroup.

Comment: i cannot use radiogroup

Comment: What is the reason behind that?

Comment: as i have each diiferent row it will behave differently.so how can i use radiogroup in custom listview??

Comment: Have you try my ans ?

Comment: ya ,i am not able to select any checkbox @ Haresh Chhelana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change all item boolean value false exclude selected item after notify adapter and  also implement [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) design pattern for ListView performance :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list,null);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt1.setText(items.get(position));
        holder.chkbox.setChecked(array[position]);
        holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                    if(i==position){
                        array[i]=true;
                    }else{
                        array[i]=false;
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView txt1;
        CheckBox chkbox;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to keep track of selected item and code accordingly.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Integer selected_position = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Your Code

            chkbox.setChecked(position==selected_position);

            chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        selected_position =  position;
                    }
                    else{
                         selected_position = -1;
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;


        }
}
```

Comment: do i need to use setonCheckedChangeListner ,can't i use onclick??

Comment: then for selecting another checkbox .do i need to re load the whole listview??

Comment: [setonCheckedChangeListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) is called when checked state of a compound button changed which is particularly introduced for CheckBox

Comment: try this code, if it doesn't show new checked item, use `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `setonCheckedChangeListner`

Comment: i can still select multiple checkbox @SweetWisher ツ

Comment: ya its working but i cannot deselect same checkbox once i select it.

Comment: add the else part and assign -1 to `selected_position`

Comment: but the chkbox.setChecked(position==selected_position); Intern calls  onchecked change listner

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Sweet wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a variable:

```
int checked = -1;  //say
```

Whenever you try to check a checkbox you check this variable, if it is -1 then check the checkbox and save the position of the list item in checked variable, when you try to check other checkbox again, if the variable ain't equal to -1 you first uncheck the checkbox at the position stored in checked variable, and then check the checkbox at current position and save the current position in checked variable

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v=convertView;
        final int pos=position;
        if(v==null)
        {
            v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list,null);
        }

        TextView txt1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final CheckBox chkbox=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        txt1.setText(items.get(position));
        int selectedindexitem=0;

        if(position==selected_position)
        {
            chkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            chkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
        chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(chkbox.isChecked())
                {
                    array[pos]=true;
                    selected_position =  pos;
                }else{
                    array[pos]=false;
                }
            }
        }); 
        chkbox.setChecked(array[pos]);
         MainActivity.lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context,MainActivity.listitems));




        return v; 
    }
```

Comment: write  notifyDataSetChanged(); in `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

Easy to maintain your selection. Get your selection from the model.

```
 class PropertyModel{
 String VAL= "SOME VALUE"
 boolean selected = false;

public String getVAL() {return VAL;}
public void setVAL(String VAL) {this.VAL = VAL;}
public boolean isSelected() {return selected;}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {this.selected = selected;} 
}
```

Prepare your view like this:

```
  public class CheckBoxAdptr extends BaseAdapter{
  /*       
   ..........
  */

  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    PropertyModel items = list.get(position);
    View row;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_checkbox, null);
    }
    else{row = view;}

    TextView T1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_1);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_check_box);

    T1.setText(""+items.getVAL());
    if(items.isSelected()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {checkBox.setChecked(false);}

    return row;
}
}
```

Now in your activity or fragment set the adapter and do something like this:

```
   final ArrayList<PropertyModel> list = getList();
    CheckBoxAdptr adpt = new CheckBoxAdptr(getActivity(), list);
    listview.setAdapter(adpt);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if(i!=position){
                    list.get(i).setSelected(false);
                }
                else{
                    list.get(i).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
            adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Notice that all your work is done by `adpt.notifyDataSetChanged()` . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Working with *getView* (like most of the answers posted) was not working properly for me. It was not responsive enough. Sometimes it would uncheck the previous checkbox, sometimes not.

This worked perfectly for me:

First we need to store the position of all previously checked checkboxes:

```
Set<Integer> selectedPreviousPositions = new HashSet<>();
```

Then in the onItemClick listener we uncheck **all** checkboxes before checking the one we selected.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbSelected)).isChecked();
        if (!isChecked) {
             final ListView listDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDevices);
             for (Integer pos : selectedPreviousPositions ) {
                 View pView = listDevices.getChildAt(pos);
                 if (pView != null) { // unnecessary but we never know !
                     ((CheckBox)pView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxID)).setChecked(false);
                 }
             }
            selectedUniquePositions.add(new Integer(position));
            // Now we can check the selected checkbox
            ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbSelected)).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbSelected)).setChecked(false);
            selectedPreviousPositions.remove(new Integer(position));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the adapter, set OnClickListener() for checkBox. Whenever checkBox is clicked, store clicked checkBox position and call notifyDataSetChanged(). This will getView() method again for all views in your listview. Whenever, getView() called, you check the checkBox of previously stored postition and uncheck remaining checkboxes.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourModelObject>
{
    private int selectedCheckBoxPosition = -1;

    public int getSelectedCheckBoxPosition() 
    {
        return selectedCheckBoxPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position == selectedCheckBoxPosition)
        {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "checkbox CHECKED at pos: " + position);
        }
        else 
        {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            Log.d(TAG, "checkbox UNCHECKED at pos: " + position);
        }

        //viewHolder.checkBox.setText("sample text");

        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedCheckBoxPosition = position;
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick() - set selectedCheckBoxPosition = " + position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder 
    {
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```